# Where can get libc_p.so source code?

Tags: linux, mips, libc, gprof

I'd like to profiling my owned process in target hardware, I only can check the source code as libc.so since there is no libc_p.so available for my MIPS target hardware.
I expect:
I, There is MIPS libc_p.so library available;
OR
II,There is libc_p source code available, that I can compile the MIPS library by myself.

I'm looking forward to good proposal from you experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libc_p.so` is just a binary of libc compiled with the profiling options to the compiler/linker.  The source is the same.